# An infinite sequence of inscribed squares alternate black and white. Find the black area as a fraction of the first square's area.

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

> There is an infinite sequence of squares such that vertices of every next square lie in the center of the sides of the previous square. Odd-numbered squares are filled with white color, and even-numbered are filled with black. Find the black area as a fraction of the first square.
>
> Suggestions : 1/3 or 1/2 or 2/3 or 3/4

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker know about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort tends to give the wrong impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Answer (score 1):

If the side length of a square is $\ell$, then the side length of the inner square whose vertices are the centers of the original square is $\dfrac{\ell}{\sqrt{2}}$, and thus its area is $\dfrac{\ell^2}{2}$, which represents half of the area of the original square. Since the first square is colored in white, then the number we are looking for is :
$1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{4}-\dfrac{1}{8}+\cdots\right)=1-\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n}$

It is well known that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{2^n}=\dfrac{2}{3}$ and therefore the answer is $\dfrac{1}{3}$